# Dokku Deploy Github action, Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: docker, ssh, deployment, github-actions, dokku

Trying to set up Github actions.
Workflow is to start Dokku deployment on merged PR to main branch:
**.github/workflows/dokku.yml**

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
    types:
      - closed

jobs:
  if_merged:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
            fetch-depth: 0
      - id: deploy
        name: Deploy to dokku
        uses: idoberko2/dokku-deploy-github-action@v1
        with:
            ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
            dokku-host: '123.123.123.123'
            app-name: 'testapp'
            remote-branch: 'main'
```

Step 'Deploy to dokku' give an error:

```
            Run idoberko2/dokku-deploy-github-action@v1
            /usr/bin/docker run --name cd98f7e739ac6046d41c39b90a6cfa22a8060_137fd0 
        --label 4cd98f --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e INPUT_SSH-PRIVATE-KEY 
        -e INPUT_DOKKU-HOST -e INPUT_APP-NAME -e INPUT_REMOTE-BRANCH -e INPUT_DOKKU-USER 
        -e INPUT_GIT-PUSH-FLAGS -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA 
-e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER 
        -e GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS -e GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW 
        -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL 
        -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_REF_NAME -e GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED 
        -e GITHUB_REF_TYPE -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH 
        -e GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTION_REF -e GITHUB_PATH -e GITHUB_ENV 
        -e GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_ARCH -e RUNNER_NAME -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE 
        -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN 
        -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" 
    -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" 
    -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" 
    -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" 
    -v "/home/runner/work/test/test":"/github/workspace" 
    4cd98f:7e739ac6046d41c39b90a6cfa22a8060  "***" "dokku" "123.123.123.123" "testapp" "main" ""
            Agent pid 11
            Error loading key "(stdin)": invalid format
            # 123.123.123.123:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
            # 123.123.123.123:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
            # 123.123.123.123:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
            GIT_COMMAND=git push deploy 38f6c6ba47f4d40a7d19c5cf9a9b148ebb88996e:refs/heads/main 
            Warning: Permanently added '123.123.123.123' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
            Permission denied (publickey).
            fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
            Please make sure you have t
    
    he correct access rights
        and the repository exists.
```

**so, basically this lines:**

```
Error loading key "(stdin)": invalid format
Warning: Permanently added '123.123.123.123' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I can deploy from my local machine with `git push dokku`

I added private ssh key to github secrets.

On remote server where Dokku lives, I have this:

```
dokku ssh-keys:list
SHA256:T4rHySQTzDRguZ0t7d7NhN2DlkNF0+kBfkxMU/P0zAk NAME="admin" SSHCOMMAND_ALLOWED_KEYS="no-agent-forwarding,no-user-rc,no-X11-forwarding,no-port-forwarding"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding ssh private key - we need to add new line at the end.. facepalm.

Comment: Hey, can you please elaborate with the help of a before and after. Did you add the new line at the end of the GitHub secret containing the private key?

Comment: @DeveshKumar Hello, yes, it's correct, I just pressed Enter at the end of a line with private key.